# Salesforce DX: Portal administrator issue on User after creating scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm working on a project for German customer and I'm using Salesforce DX to work with scratch-orgs. There's a nice script to configure everything and it was working fine till Summer'18.

Since Summer'18 I'm (and entire team is) getting most of the time following error:

> Dieser Benutzer ist Portaladministrator und muss ein Profil mit der Berechtigung zur Bearbeitung von Self-Service-Benutzern besitzen.: __MISSING_LABEL_FOR_common.udd.impl.UddInfoImpl@43dfee08.

which in English would be:

> This user is a portal administrator and must have a profile with the "Edit Self-Service Users" permission

Here is beginning of our script:

```
1. sfdx force:org:create -f ./config/project-scratch-def.json -a name -s
2. sfdx force:data:record:update -s User -w "LastName=User" -v "LanguageLocaleKey=en_US CountryCode=DE" // used to change the User's language so that we can work in English
```

We get this error on step 2 when trying to change the User's language.
Most of the times means that after few attempts finally we get scratch org that doesn't fail at this step.

The same error appears when we try to update the User via UI.
[image]
We don't have any Customer Portal, nor the Community that's why it's so strange.

Here is our `project-scratch-def.json`:

```
{
    "orgName": "SomeName",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "orgPreferences" : {
        "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled", "ChatterEnabled", "EnhancedEmailEnabled"]
    },
    "features": ["LightningSalesConsole", "StateAndCountryPicklist"],
    "language": "de" // needed because without it we can't push objects and fields
}
```

I checked it with other Dev Hub and get the same error on User's update

**EDIT 19/09/2019**

On another project got the same error when trying to mark scratch org as `Marketing User` with command:

```
sfdx force:data:record:update -s User -w "Email='some@email.com'" -v "UserPermissionsMarketingUser=true"
```

The error being:

> ERROR running force:data:record:update:  This user is a portal
>   administrator and must have a profile with the "Manage Customer Users"
>   permission.: __MISSING_LABEL_FOR_common.udd.impl.UddInfoImpl@5f151d7d

Our workaround is again to keep trying until we get a proper scratch org.

Comment: I have the same issue but randomly. Some Scratch Orgs are ok and some other are not. I start talking about this here but haven't got an answer yet: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1&fId=0D53A00003h0SgA

Comment: same here. I submitted support case for this over 1 week ago but no success so far. Thanks for the link, that's exactly same issue

Comment: As a german ISV we're sitting in the same boat. Is the behaviour the same if you DO NOT update the user with '"LanguageLocaleKey=en_US CountryCode=DE" ' BUT add Country = 'US', language="en_US" to the `project-scratch-def.json`
That's how we tackle language changes for a german dev hub org. i do not know if it has any impact

Comment: Christian, this would solve the language problem (since we don't need to update User then, when trying to update it's still there), however our metadata (objects, fields) is then incompatible with scratch org and we can't push it. That's the example: `force-app\main\default\objects\Quote__c\Quote__c.object-meta.xml                                                                   Cannot specify a gender for a gender neutral language`. We would need to rewrite the metadata to English? Atm we are creating scratch orgs until we get a proper one

Comment: This has been determined to be bug.  Expect a patch in the next couple of weeks. Thanks for surfacing this issue!

Comment: I'm working on support case for this for a long time and so far received feedback from RnD team that it happens only for Enterprise edition of scratch orgs. So if using Developer is fine for you - you are probably good (I have made some testing). However, regarding Enterprise - if you need it as we do, you need to keep trying creating scratch orgs until you get a good one as there is no other workaround or patch coming (accordign to RnD and support agent)

Comment: @neff Did support give you an Known Issue number/link to track?

Comment: I published this question in the Salesforce Partner Community a while ago, but didn't receive any useful feedback. At least now I see we're not alone :) Thanks Maiquel for pointing this out!

Here's the post in the Partner Community, so we can update it too once there's an update:

https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001tczCAA&fId=0D53A00003gNb9ASAS

Comment: @JasonClark "The RnD team is still trying to identify and determine if this is a BUG and this has not been clarified yet." - that's where I ended so far... Workaround they suggest is to use Developer scratch orgs instead of Enterprise

Comment: Considering that my project, so far developed against an Enterprise scratch org, won't actually deploy to a DE scratch org (5 different errors), that's not much of a workaround.  Love the promise of DX but my forehead is getting bruised.

Comment: An observation:  I created to identical scratch orgs, one today, one yesterday.  I was able to edit my user record in yesterday's scratch org, but not in today's scratch org (due to the "Edit Self-Service Users") message.  However, there was another difference - yesterday's scratch org contains another user, "Pooled Org Admin", and that user is the Portal Admin.  So while I can edit my user, I have an extra user in the org that cannot be edited or de-activated.  This is a problem given that we are limited to 5 "Salesforce" user licenses in a scratch org.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dave Carroll in the question's comments, this appears to be a bug.   A patch should be coming soon.

In the mean time, the workaround is to use "Developer" as the scratch org edition.

Comment: Vivek, this still seems to be open. I just ran into this when using the CircleCI part of your Falcon template. It defines the test scratch org as an Enterprise edition.

Comment: @RobertSösemann - I'll reach out to the product team to see if I can get a status update.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in the dev forums:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005qljQAA

This worked for me when I got this error updating in a full sandbox.